# Past perfect or past simple?which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

1-He was very excited to have been invited to Matt's party.The last time he **was** at a party, he **had (got-BE)/(gotten-AE)** so drunk that he was unable to get back home.

2-He was very excited to have been invited to Matt's party.The last time he **was** at a party, he **got** so drunk that he was unable to get back home.

3-He was very excited to have been invited to Matt's party.The last time he **had been to** a party he **had (got-BE)/(gotten-AE)** so drunk that he was unable to get back home.

4-He was very excited to have been invited to Matt's party.The last time he **had been to** a party he **got** so drunk that he was unable to get back home.
Could someone elo

Answer (score 1):

All four possibilities are fine. English speakers don't necessarily use the past perfect when the temporal relationships are clear without, and there is not a need to set a temporal focus.

I think 2 is slightly less likely than any of the others, because in the other cases at least one of the verbs set it in the past of the past; but even without that, no 2 is possible, especially if there is further context that makes it clear that that last time was before Matt's party.

Answer (score 0):

The last time he had been to a party he had gotten so drunk  that he had been unable to walk home. Past perfect is used because that party took place before this party, which is yet to come . "He was excited" is set in the past ( past simple is used) and anything happening before that is in past perfect. I think "was" should be in past perfect too.

Comment: I think the last time refers to a specific moment and past perfect is mandatory